# Logrotate rotating daily but should be rotating weekly

Tags: cron, logrotate

For some reason logrotate is rotating logs daily instead of weekly, even though all the config files for logrotate seem to be set to weekly. Any ideas?

**/etc/cron.daily/logrotate**

```
#!/bin/sh

test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

**/etc/logrotate.conf**

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}


# system-specific logs may be configured here
```

**/etc/logrotate.d/apache**

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        weekly
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if [ -f "`. /etc/apache2/envvars ; echo ${APACHE_PID_FILE:-/var/run/apache2.pid}`" ]; then
                        /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
                fi
        endscript
}
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Notice this line in `/etc/logrorate.conf`:

```
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

Perhaps you have some stale or backup files lying around in that directory, which get included, and specify daily rotation?

As a workaround, and if you still can't figure it out, and if you only ever want to have your files rotated weekly, then you can change the frequency with which `logrotate` is executed through cron, thus changing the precision of log rotation from daily to weekly.

Comment: The program-specific logrotate files in /etc/logrotate.d are actually what I want to run, my particular interest in this case being the Apache logrotate config file I posted above. There is only one apache file in that directory. No forgotten backups. Also, I'm trying to avoid using cron.weekly for this, as the impression I get is that that violates best practices.

Comment: For me, in `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2`, the rotation was configured to occur `daily`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to force a rotation manually so it reloads the configuration:

```
sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Also... don't force it on your crontab, there keep it without flags:

```
#logrotate
0  0    * * *   /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```